# Im scared of my dads yelling at me for little things

Tags: fears, depression

So i cleaned my room and i was in a hurry so forgot to do the bed and forgot to close a cabinet, when i get home my dad starts screaming at me and this always happens and i always cry and now i'm depressed and want to die but i'm christian and scared to kill myself what do i do? I"v already tried to avoid it or be perfect but that didn't work,i mean he yelled at me for having a sock on the ground.yes i have a mom and a dad and also a brother and a sister but he doesn't yell at them like that.

Comment: Could you provide more information, like your age and your family status (do you have brothers/sisters, is your mom present and so on) ?

Comment: yes i have a mom married to my dad and a brother and a sister but only i get treated like this.

Comment: If your brother and sister are older they may already have gone through that yelling phase.

Comment: You clearly need help, but I'm sorry, this isn't the place to get it. We can give advice in response to specific questions, but this is too broad. You don't say where you live or how old you are, but most places have some kind of help-line for children who feel like you do. (in the UK its The Samaritans or ChildLine). I think you should find out what that is in your area, and give them a call. You can talk things over with them, and maybe they can give you some useful advice or pointers to places where you can escape. Good luck, and stay strong.

Answer (score 5):

It's a good first step that you asked for help. But your problem can't be solved by random people on the internet and therefore isn't a good fit for this web site.

But there *are* people who can help you to be resilient, to change the situation at home or to get you out of this situation, whatever might in the end be the best.

- Is there some relative that you trust that you might ask to help you?
- Is there a teacher that you can trust?
- You might talk to your doctor.
- Your might talk to the parents of close friends.
- You mention you're religious. Maybe there is someone at church who can help?

Depending of where you live and your age, doctors and priests might be forbidden by law to share any information you provide with your parents, unless you agree. If this is important, you can search about that online, or just ask them about it before you talk more.

If you cannot think of anybody you already know, that you trust and that might be of help, there will be telephone hotlines (as mentioned in a comment) and the authorities (child protection services or whatever those are called where you come from). This very much depends on where you are living, but a search on the internet ("children help line", "child service" or in case of suicidal thoughts "suicide hotline" combined with your locality) and on the homepage of your local council should provide you with phone numbers or mail addresses where you can get help.

Comment: I'm a Christian, and even I would say talk to a helpline, doctor, or teacher before a church member. Such professionals are trained and less likely to out the child to the parents out of good spiritual intentions.

Comment: I'm an atheist, so I'm far from recommending religion and church as a solution. But, depending on the church and child, I acknowledge that there may be an existing trust relationship that may be of use. But yes, there's a reason why I put church last in the list of already established relationships.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Maybe not random lay members at the church, but the ministers/priests should be reliable. I'd be surprised if they didn't have classes on how to handle this sort of thing as part of their ministerial training.